# Find the highest odd number in an array using recursion in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

```java
public static int highestOdd(int [] arr, int index)
{
  if(arr.length-1 == index) return arr[index];
  int high = highestOdd(arr,index+1);
  high = high > arr[index] ? high : arr[index];
  return high;
}
```

the index always passes as 0, so this code will check all the numbers including even numbers but I just want to output the highest odd number.
I hope somebody will help me
Thanks before.

Comment: By odd, you meant odd index numbers or odd numbers?

Comment: good question to make sure that you don't learn anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While replacing the value of high with arr[index] if arr[index] value is higher just check if the value is odd. Else keep the high value as it is. Try the following code. It will return -1 if there have no odd value in the array(assuming all the values of array are positive, if there have possibility of negative value then you can replace -1 with integer min). Let me know if you don't understand any part.

```
public static int highestOdd(int [] arr, int index) {
   if(arr.length - 1 == index) return arr[index] % 2 > 0 ? arr[index] : -1;
   int high = highestOdd(arr,index+1);
   if(arr[index] % 2 > 0) high = high > arr[index] ? high : arr[index];
   return high;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update high only when you encounter an odd Integer.

```
public static int highestOdd(int[] arr, int index) {
        // When last Integer is odd.
        if (index == arr.length - 1 && arr[index] % 2 != 0) {
            return arr[index];
        }
        // When last Integer is even.
        else if(index == arr.length - 1)
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;

        int high = highestOdd(arr, index+1);
        //Update high only when current index has odd.
        if(arr[index]%2 != 0){
            high = high > arr[index] ? high : arr[index];
        }
        return high;
    }
```

Comment: Careful with this `arr[index] % 2 == 1`. It would be better to express it like this `arr[index] % 2 != 0` to include negative numbers.

Comment: But shouldn't `a%n` always return a positive integer in range `0 to n-1`. Speaking mathematically.

Comment: Actually, you can express every remainder as a negative number. There's a lot of discussion around this. In practice, depending on the programming language, you will get either a negative or positive number, so to make sure, no matter its sign, it's better to express it as `!= 0`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Use to think `%` operator is similar to Mathematical `modular` function which always returns a positive integer. Will make the change in the answer.